# Mysql error with my SELECT DISTINCT query

Tags: mysql, function

I keep running into the same error, using MySQL.

The *totaal* value is marked as wrong, but i have no idea what is wrong with the function at all.

[My original code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohaV9.png)

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION functiondave
 (p_in date)
 return date is sumMediaExpression int;

 begin;

 select distinct count(Beoordelingen) into totaal
 from media_uitingen
 where Beoordelingen like 'Positief' and DATUM like '01-07-14';

 dbms_output.put_line('Number of positive MediaExpressions op 01-07-14 
 zijn : ' || sumMediaExpression);

 end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Edit your question and add the code here, it is easier for us to have the code in case we need to debug it (add four spaces before every line and it will apear here formatted as code.). Your problem is because you are using Oracle syntax instead of MySql. See here how to define a procedure/function in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Please dont post pictures of your code. Post your code as text in the question

Comment: Your code has too many issues. One is that `totaal` is not declared. Please read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Answer (score 0):

> The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

Your query is wrong.
You need to write it like this:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Beoordelingen) INTO totaal FROM media_uitingen (the rest of your query);`

*You can check this website for further information about SQL queries: https://www.w3schools.com/sql*